# Can a Guest Lecturer be my Referee?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have a guest lecturer who taught me one module for one semester and graded my work. He is willing to be my referee. Would he be counted as an acceptable referee if I were applying to be admitted for a PhD (graduate admission)?

Edit: I would like to mention that I asked because I was just worried because I don't know if it's standard practice to accept such referees even if they have taught me for one full semester, and some bureaucrats who may act as gatekeepers to academic staff might err on the side of caution almost to the point of inflexibility.

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea what you're applying for.  I don't see how we can help without knowing who will read the reference.

Comment: You mean for graduate admissions? (From the tag) i mean, why not? What leads you to believe that it could not be the case?

Comment: Hi, Anonymous Physicist and user 111388; yes, for graduate admissions. I will amend my question accordingly. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Could you amebd you question to write why you think this would be not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a Guest Lecturer be my Referee?

Yes, they can. To determine if they are the *best* referee for a graduate application, try answering the following questions:

- Can this person attest for my **strong research potential?** (Not just performance in coursework) (e.g. did you talk to them after lecture about ideas outside the scope of the course? Did they seem interested in discussion research-level topics with you?)
- Will this person's name (or at least their University affiliation) be recognized by the admissions committee or by the professors whose groups you apply to?

If the guest lecturer satisfies one or both of those criteria, they could be a good choice. If they don't satisfy them, see if there is someone else who would satisfy them. It is still a trade-off here -- someone who knows you better is more likely to give a good letter than someone who does not know you as well. It may be that the guest lecturer is the best choice even if they do not satisfy these criteria, in the case that no one else really does either.